# Search button Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, search, button

I am having issues with getting a Search button to work in my Netbeans program.
Quick info about my program:Cars are saved in records and i am trying to search them by ID,if the ID matches with a car's ID,some of their details should be displayed.However even if i keep typing the correct ID's,i keep getting the error:Car not found.Could anyone provide any details for me to solve this issue?I have come to a point where i have no idea how to get this to work.Thank you for your time

Code:

```
    int cID = Integer.parseInt(txtID.getText());
    int f = 0;

    Rentals r2 = new Rentals();
    Rentals r3 = new Rentals();
    boolean found = false;

    for(int i = 0;i<carRentalList.size();i++)
    {
        r2 = (Rentals) carRentalList.get(i);
        if(r2.getID()==cID)
        {
            found = true;
            record = i;
            r3=r2;
        }

    }
    if(found)
    {
        txtModel.setText(r3.getModel());
        txtDoors.setText(Integer.toString(r3.getDoors()));
        txtPassengers.setText(Integer.toString(r3.getPassengers()));
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Car not found.");
    }
```

Comment: For best help, please consider creating and posting a small but simple complete program that illustrates your problem, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please check the link for the details of this very useful tool.

Comment: No, none of us can do that, but still try to create as decent an mcve as you are able to make and post what you have. Again it won't be wasted effort. Comment back if you change your question and especially if you add code.

Comment: I have found the solution =).Thank you for trying to help Hover

Comment: Glad you've solved your issue, but please let us know: What was the problem/solution?

Comment: the problem was here:if(r2.getID()==cID)
      getID was getting an unused variable instead of the vehicle ID that i desired to get